# Piping in exec* POSIX functions

Tags: c, linux, pipe, exec, posix

How to convert:

```
system("ps -el | grep fork")
```

argument to an `execlp` function?

I've tried:

```
execlp("ps", "ps", "-el", "|", "grep", "fork", (char*)0)
```

and:

```
execlp("ps", "ps", "-el", "grep", "fork1", (char*)0)
```

but both don't work. Is it feasible or not?

Answer (score 3):

Piping is not an automatic feature on POSIX systems, you have to implement it yourself.

For this you have the [`pipe`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) and [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) system calls.

The [`pipe`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) function creates a pair of file descriptors, one where you write to, and one where you read from. The [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) function "forks" a new process.

The trick is to create a pipe using the `pipe` function, and create a child process. The parent process could then use the write file descriptor of the pipe to be mapped to the standard output of the process (usually done using the [`dup2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) function). Then the parent process `exec` the first (left-hand side) command of the pipe.

The child process takes the read descriptor of the pipe, and maps it to the standard input, and the similarly `exec` the command for the other (right-hand side) of the pipe.

This will lead to all output from the first command to standard output to be piped to the standard input of the second command.

There are many tutorials and examples all over the Internet on how to do this practically.

Comment: Thanks, I will do some search and try it.